# Docker Error: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint, docker-exec

I have created a docker image named ocp-install from the following dockerfile

```
    FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:latest

    ARG INSTALL_DIR=/root/install-dir

    ENV PATH $PATH:$INSTALL_DIR

    WORKDIR $INSTALL_DIR

    RUN microdnf update && \
        microdnf install -y yum findutils && \
        mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR

    COPY ocp-install $INSTALL_DIR

    ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/usr/bin/ocp-install"]
```

I have run the command `docker run -it ocp-install create` for installation.

And now i want to destroy the install using command `docker exec -it <containerID> destroy`
, however it gives the following error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"destroy\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly uninstall anything, or is deleting the container enough?  (I'd normally expect the image to contain everything it needs, and not do additional installation at startup time; can you `RUN ocp-install create`, omit the `ENTRYPOINT`, and set the `CMD` to actually run the installed program?)

Comment: Actually, the purpose of creating the image is to allow installing as well as uninstalling. Since the image has `ENTRYPOINT` pointing to a script, it allows both. The problem I am facing is sometimes after installation is done, the container goes in a stopped state and starting the containing again to explicitly run `destroy` command somehow triggers the `create`

Comment: Where does it install it?  What happens after it's installed?

Comment: The create command installs a cluster and destroy command deletes it. There are executables stored in the workdir, however during the `create` it does not use the existing executables but downloads executables in the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

short answer:

`exec` runs a new command, destroy is the subcommand of `ocp-install`, so you have to specify the whole command:

```
docker exec -it <containerID> -- /usr/bin/ocp-install destroy
```

### explanation

as https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint describe,

> Command line arguments to docker run  will be appended after all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT

`ENTRYPOINT` works for `docker run` but not `docker exec`

as https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/ describe,

> The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container.

When you are trying the `docker exec -it <containerID> destroy` command, docker tried to run the command `destroy` instead of appending `destroy` args to `ocp-install`